# Preg_match_all not working on yahoo results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Ok, so the preg_match_all wont work towards Yahoo.

I'm trying to preg_match_all the results i get from Yahoo using a cURL curl_multi_getcontent method.

I have succeeded to fetch the site and so, but when I'm trying to get the result of the links, it wont match anything. When I'm using the regex in Notepad++ it succeeds but not in PHP apparently.

I'm currently using:

```
preg_match_all(
    '#<span class="url" id="(.*?)">(.+?)</span>#si', $urlContents[2], $yahoo
);
```

Check the HTML at `[http://se.search.yahoo.com/search?p=random&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t][1]` for example and you will see that all links start with `<span class="url" id="something random">` and ends with `</span>`.

Could someone possible help me with how I should retreive this information?
I only need the actual link address to each result.

### Entire PHP Script

```
public function multiSearch($question)
{
    $sites['google'] = "http://www.google.com/search?q={$question}&gl=sv";
    $sites['bing'] = "http://www.bing.com/search?q={$question}";
    $sites['yahoo'] = "http://se.search.yahoo.com/search?p={$question}";

    $urlHandler = array();

    foreach($sites as $site)
    {
        $handler = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        array_push($urlHandler, $handler);
    }

    $multiHandler = curl_multi_init();
    foreach($urlHandler as $key => $url)
    {
        curl_multi_add_handle($multiHandler, $url);
    }

    $running = null;
    do
    {
        curl_multi_exec($multiHandler, $running);
    }
    while($running > 0);

    $urlContents = array();
    foreach($urlHandler as $key => $url)
    {
        $urlContents[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent($url);
    }

    foreach($urlHandler as $key => $url)
    {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($multiHandler, $url);
    }

    foreach($urlContents as $urlContent)
    {
        preg_match_all('/<li class="g">(.*?)<\/li>/si', $urlContent, $matches);
        //$this->view_data['results'][] = "Random";
    }
    preg_match_all('#<cite>(.+?)</cite>#si', $urlContents[1], $googleLinks);
    preg_match_all('#<span class="url" id="(.*)">(.+?)</span>#si', $urlContents[2], $yahoo);
    var_dump($yahoo);
    die();
    $findHtml = array('/<cite>/', '/<\/cite>/', '/<b>/', '/<\/b>/', '/ /', '/"/', '/<strong>/', '/<\/strong>/');
    $removeHtml = array('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
    foreach($googleLinks as $links => $val)
    {
        foreach($val as $link)
            $this->view_data['results'][] = preg_replace($findHtml, $removeHtml, $link);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better look into the HTML you receive first, in the bare HTML there is no `<span class="url"` in there. It is less the `preg_match` but more that you look for something existent.

Comment: @hakre I have printed out the content for Yahoo several times, checked over an over again if <span class="url" really exists, and yes, it does. And what do you mean by "in the bare HTML there is no <span class="url""? Because I can see find it.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, because I just looked into the source of the link you gave and I could not find the `<span class="url"` (single space between tagname and attributename) literal string. I only find it in the DOM after javascript has been executed. Curl does not execute javascript.

Comment: @hakre This is exactly what I copied from http://se.search.yahoo.com/search?p=random&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t

    <span class="url" id="yui_3_3_0_1_1350463678334192">www.<b id="yui_3_3_0_1_1350463678334191">random.org</b></span>

Comment: For me in the source it looks like `<span class=url>`, that is without the double-quotes around the attribute value. Edit: http://i.imgur.com/qzyBd.png - The benefit of the HTML parser that Jack suggests is that it normalizes the structure for you so you can more easily access what you look for.

Comment: Woa, you are right! When I print out the HTML document and look through the source, google chrome auto adds the "" quotes around the attribute. Thanks a lot for your respons!

Comment: The screenshot I've added is from google chrome. Just use CTRL+U to view the source, you will see it verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should not use regular expressions to process HTML. There are pretty good DOM parsers available for PHP. For example:

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($s);
$x = new DOMXPath($d);
foreach ($x->query('//span[@class="url"]') as $node) {
        // process each node the way you wish
        // print the id for instance
        echo $node->getAttribute('id'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Besides that, the expression should work except that `id="(.*)"` is greedy; that can be fixed with:

```
#<span class="url" id="(.*?)">(.+?)</span>#si
```

It's possible that there's more text after `id="..."` and the `>`; that would bring the expression to:

```
#<span class="url" id="(.*?)"[^>]*>(.+?)</span>#si
```

Comment: Hi again @Jack. As I mentioned before. It won't work even tho I use that. It wont match anything.

Comment: @DanielRunnakkoLöfgren It works fine for `<span class="url" id="yui_3_3_0_1_1350462992855206">www.<b id="yui_3_3_0_1_1350462992855205">random.org</b></span>`

Comment: I'll look more into it. Also I know I shouldn't use regex for processing HTML, but for this particular assignment, I am requested to do so, thats why I'm using it.

Comment: @DanielRunnakkoLöfgren The person who requested that must have a sick sense of humour; in any case, I've updated the answer ... hope it helps.

Comment: @DanielRunnakkoLöfgren You should also make sure that you're matching against the correct content ... does `urlContents[2]` really contain the Yahoo page?